# Searching for people on Facebook not using a conventional characters in their names

Tags: facebook, search

It's true not everyone uses their real name on Facebook, but there are some who doesn't even use "real" and generally used characters in it.

For example one can keep their name `β₳₮MAN` on Facebook, and it would even accept that name. Well there are hundreds of thousands of people using such "unconventional" characters in their name to "stylize" or look cool, which, for me isn't.

Recently, I asked a person if he was on Facebook, and he told me yes and his name is "Mr Rohit" but the `r` in `Mr` is not what it should generally be. I tried searching for "Mr Rohit" but no results, and maybe it's due to the weird form of `r` he might be using.

So my question is, is there any easy way to search for the name, despite of it containing a letter/character that somehow represents an alphabet but not actually one.

Answer (score 1):

For these kind of issues you can search that person with their registered email id in Facebook. Where it will list the person tough they have special characters in name.

Hope this helps